# Spark view engine with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, template-engine, spark-view-engine

I've used Spark view engine(http://sparkviewengine.com/) with ASP.NET and I really liked it.

Is there any port or similar template engine in Node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark doesn't need ASP.NET to operate. It's capable of running from the console if you want to and it runs on Windows and Linux and only really needs access to the C# compiler on Windows or in Mono on Linux. So really the question is, what does your configuration with Node.js look like, and can you configure it so that it offloads the output to a templating engine like Spark?

There have been [many console driven apps](https://github.com/loudej/spark/tree/master/src/Samples/DirectUsage) totally separated from ASP.NET which can be used as a starting point to get something running in this kind of scenario. All you need to make sure is that you have access to a C# compiler or you could precompile your views for DLL deployment in which case all you'll need on the machine is the .Net Framework or Mono runtime.

Hope that helps,
Rob